# Why is the javascript object prototype referred to as `fn`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the etymology of such terminology?  Where does it come from?  What does it stand for?

Comment: Do you mean `jQuery.fn`? I don't think `fn` has special meaning in the Javascript language *per se*...

Comment: Oh, ok.  My bad.  So sure. Why is it called `fn`?

Comment: because `fu` was too offensive.

Answer (score 4):

`fn` is the traditional abbreviation for `function`.

`jQuery.fn` is an object, sometimes called a namespace, that is exposed by the [global `jQuery` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/properties/global-jquery-object-properties/). Functions that are members of `jQuery.fn` can be applied to [jQuery objects](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery):

```
$("#foo").hide();  // Here, 'hide()' is actually '$.fn.hide()'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The etymology is mathematical. f(n) is mathematical nomenclature representing a function.

Comment: The mathematical etymology is f(x) normally though, not n

Comment: @AlexW in computer science we generally use `n` instead of `x` (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Defining_complexity_classes))

Answer (score 1):

It's used in jQuery to be the property where plugins can assign themselves. It means `function` as all plugins are self executing functions.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

The javascript object prototype property is called just that: `object.prototype` and is used to help with object oriented JS.